# Double Click event preventDefault() not stopping the execution?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to prevent docuble click on my entire Page so the reason i have selected *

This is the code i kept to prevent docuble clicks

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '*', function(e){  
alert('dbclick prevented');
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8uac7/3010/

But the issue i am facing is that this is coming into the condition but not stoping  the execution ??

Comment: can you check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/8uac7/3012/)

Comment: Why not use `.one()`

Comment: he wants to prevent .one() will still run right? :) but only once

Comment: @guradio thanks for the demo , but still i am facing the same issue .

Comment: @PreethiJain what issue?when you double click on the demo no alert will show right?isnt that what you want?

Comment: is it possible to stop the execution itself

Comment: Do you want to stopPropagation or what ?

Comment: well i think that is what the demo does

Comment: For example when double clicked on Batman , it should not be navigated

Comment: sorry @PreethiJain but the navigation i think is not on double click it is on click only

Comment: and single click always will happened before the double click and you cant do a double click first before a single click

Answer (score 0):

You must remove **'*'**. I don't see any point using that. jQuery catches the double click event without that, as well. You can have:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', function(e){ /* your code */ });
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to convey. Check out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8uac7/3013/)

Answer (score 0):

Use   `return false;` instead of `e.preventDefault();` it will work.

For more info [Click Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation)